# VBA Find and replace all cells found in worksheet with format found in column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a vba code snippet to get me started.

I have a column in one of my worksheets that has values (non-unique). From this column I need to either

1. Replace all found cells in the entire workbook that have the same value with the format found in the original cell or
2. If the cell has no background color to assign it a new unique color background (unique is based on previous cells in the column) and find and replace all cells in the entire workbook with this format.

I don't believe I can use conditional formatting for I have too many cells that would meet the criteria and it would slow excel down to an unacceptable speed.

Comment: The first thing most people are going to ask is if you have tried anything. The first issue I see is there are only 16.6 million RGB combos that can be made. A workbook has more cells then that and the difference in color from 240, 95, 0 to 241, 95, 0 is going to be so slight that they might as well be the same color. Depending on the number of values in your first column and the number of used cells in your workbook this could take a while to run.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The one column is part of a legend for the worksheets that appear after. I don't beleive that I'll have that many different values in the legend column. I can iterate through the column and use code snippets to find and replace but I have yet to figure out how to create a new unique colour for each unique entry in the col.

If in a macro its ok that it takes a long time to run. I just want to be able to be the one that triggers in on a function call instead of the conditional format which is all the time.

Comment: If your first column does not have unique values then how are you going to know which background color to pick? For example if A1 has a value of 10 and is Orange but A23 has a value of 10 and is Pink.

Comment: You can use `.Find` to achieve what you want? See if [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) helps

Comment: How many such values are you trying to search and change the back color of the cell? 10? 20? 100?

Comment: AxGryndr. They would both be the same colour. 
Siddharth Rout. Thank you I will try this. 

I think I'll repost with a more specific question of how to generate unique background colours.

Comment: I'm looking to replace between 10 and 10k per entry. There are several worksheets in this workbook.

Comment: Do you want all cells with the same value to have the same background? For example if the value 11 is in your workbook 15 times should all 15 have the same background color?

Comment: AxGryndr. Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Tolure: What you want is pretty simple. you can store the color in a variable and simply increment it every time you want a new color. :)

Comment: @Tolure: You can use this `rng.Interior.Color = RGB(X,Y,Z)` to create a new color. Where X, Y, Z are variables. You may search google more on using RGB to color cells.

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look into finding a way to generate different unique colours using RGB(X,Y,Z) thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so based on the prior comments here is what I have so far.

```
Sub FormatFill()
Dim sRng As Range
Dim cCell As Range
Dim nCell As Range
Dim bClr, lVal
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Range("B1").Select
     Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
     Set sRng = Selection
     'Fill all legend formats
     Range("A1").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     For Each cell In Selection
         lVal = cell.Value
         bClr = cell.Interior.Color
         Set cCell = sRng.Find(What:=lVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
         If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
             Set nCell = cCell
                 Do
                      cCell.Interior.Color = bClr
                      Set cCell = sRng.FindNext(After:=cCell)
                      If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
                            If cCell.Address = nCell.Address Then Exit Do
                      Else
                            Exit Do
                      End If
                 Loop
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am still working out how to capture and assign the unique colors for the other values on the rest of the workbook.